# XLL Excel addin in unmanaged C++

Tags: c++, excel, add-in, xll

I have a few mathematical simulations in unmanaged C++ and now I need to integrate them with Excel (so that it is  possible to call the functions from Excel and get the values back). I don't want to use any VBA, so I guess I have to implement an XLL addin. I would like to use as few third party additional frameworks as possible. Could someone point me to a good tutorial?

Comment: It's more than a tutorial, but this book contains pretty much everything you need to know to write a C++ XLL: http://www.amazon.com/Financial-Applications-using-Development-Finance/dp/0470027975/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1307629587&sr=8-1 . It also has a disk with some code for XLOPER classes that is third-party, but it's source code, and not a heavy framework.

Answer (score 14):

Starting out with the SDK can be a bit unpleasant.
I'd suggest you try one of the toolkits:

- XLW (http://xlw.sourceforge.net/) is a standard open-source C/C++ wrapper.
- Keith Lewis's NXLL library (http://nxll.codeplex.com/) might be worth a look if you are feeling a bit more adventurous, and like modern-looking C++.
- The Rolls-Royce of C/C++ toolkits for Excel is XLL+ (http://www.planatechsolutions.com/xllplus/).

Of course for managed code, or to make a C# wrapper that calls your unmanaged C++ code from .NET UDFs, you'd use Excel-DNA (http://exceldna.codeplex.com).